# Add my applications to Vista's Start Search

Tags: windows-vista

It's not a programming questions.  But this question has been bugging me for awhile.

You know when you start typing in Start Search box in Vista Start Menu, applications are appearing in the list from which you can select them.
My question is how can I add my applications so they appear in that list.

For example: I use many apps from [Sysinternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/default.aspx) like Process Explorer, AutoRun, .... I would like to launch them by starting typing and as soon as they appear in the list start the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you add them in the startmenu items in your installation then Vista will filter them when your user types there. A simple thing to do is to drag an executable with your right click in your start items list and say create shortcut here.

Comment: It adds it to the Start Menu.  I don't want to clutter my Start Menu. Plus it still doesn't appear in the search result.  I hope there's another solution.